# Python CGI using JQuery fadeIn/fadeOut effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, fadein, fadeout

I'm trying to use the fadeIn effect with jQuery in my python cgi code.

But for some reason it isn't working.

My python cgi code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Import modules for CGI handling 
import cgi, cgitb 

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

# Get data from fields
full_name = form.getvalue('fullname1')
address  = form.getvalue('address1')
phone  = form.getvalue('phone1')

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Python</title>"
print """
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#pad').hide().fadeIn(800).delay(3000).fadeOut(800);
</script>
"""
print "</head>"
print "<body id='two'>"
print "<h2>Full Name: %s</h2>" % (full_name)
print "<h2>Address %s</h2>" % (address)
print "<h2 id='pad'>Phone #: %s</h2>" % (phone)
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

I'm trying to fadeIn that third h2 with the id: pad.

This is what I'm using to fadeIn and fadeOut

```
$('#pad').hide().fadeIn(800).delay(3000).fadeOut(800);
```

It doesn't fade in nor fade out.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your script is placed above `#pad`, it is executing before `#pad` loads. Either place the script at the end of the `<body>` or wrap it in [`$(document).ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pad').hide().fadeIn(800).delay(3000).fadeOut(800); 
});
```